# Wrapper design in C++

Tags: c++, thread-safety, rcf

I am doing some c++ work designing a simulator to use in a test framework.
Anyways, the system under test is exposing a RCF API which I am using extensivly. The problem is that I am only allowed (to simulate the real system) to have a single "RCF client" per connection. This means i will have to make the use of the clients thread safe.

Normally I would call a RCF method by just by name:

```
client->methodA(param);
```

Now instead I have to (I think) wrap each and every method in a method containing a mutex call:

```
virtual class RCFClientWrapper
{
protected:
    boost::mutex mtx;
public:
    virtual RCFClientWrapper();
}

class FunctionAClient:RCFClientWrapper
{
private:
    boost::shared_ptr<RcfClient<IRCFFunctionA_IDL> > client;
public:
    /*....Stuff....*/
    void methodA(param)
    {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mtx);
        client->methodA(param);
    }
}
```

First of all is there a better way of doing this?
Second, is there a way to do all of these small methods "automatically"? Instead of having to do this for each any every method? It seems like alot of unnecessary copy/pasta.

Comment: [Maybe this is it](https://code.google.com/p/rcf-cpp/)

Comment: Oh, googling "rcf client" it's probably the Remote Call Framework, yet another RPC thingy. Of old, technologies like Corba and DCOM and the Java thingy, whatever, were all supported by code generators which took care of the wrappers.

Comment: Ohh, sorry forgot to mention what RCF is. http://www.deltavsoft.com/RCF.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you consider using a proxy class that is used to implement the [Proxy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) in which an object is an interface or a mediator for some other object.